# Need to modify VBA script to create tabs based on item codes and subsequent information for them

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet ‘Sheet1’ that looks like this:

| ItemCode | ItemDescr | UnitNo | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD010204 | ABCD010204 description | U1234 | 10 |
| ABCD010204 | ABCD010204 description | U3421 | 10 |
| ABCD020206 | ABCD020206 description | U2345 | 30 |
| ABCD020206 | ABCD020206 description | U3542 | 30 |
| ABCD020206 | ABCD020206 description | U2456 | 30 |
| ABCD020408 | ABCD020408 description | U3456 | 20 |
| BCDE010203 | BCDE010203 description | U4567 | 5 |
| BCDE010203 | BCDE010203 description | U6457 | 5 |
| BCDE020206 | BCDE020206 description | U5678 | 15 |
| BCDE020206 | BCDE020206 description | U8567 | 15 |
| BCDE020410 | BCDE020410 description | U6789 | 20 |

The ItemCodes (about 40 of them) continue and are not standard logic and not always the same. But they are always 4 letters followed by usually 6 numbers, sometimes 4.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

1. Currently, I am able to create separate tabs for each item type (So, ABCD010204, ABCD020206, etc in the same tab. BCDE0100203, BCDE020206, BCDE020410, etc in another tab.)
   I would like to modify my VBA script to take all the data from ‘Sheet1’ and create tabs for each ItemCode and their subsequent data (like below). So, one unique item per tab.

| ItemCode | ItemDescr | UnitNo | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD010204 | ABCD010204 description | U1234 | 10 |
|  |  | U3421 | 10 |

| ItemCode | ItemDescr | UnitNo | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD020206 | ABCD020206 description | U2345 | 30 |
|  |  | U3542 | 30 |
|  |  | U2456 | 30 |

| ItemCode | ItemDescr | UnitNo | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BCDE010203 | BCDE010203 description | U4567 | 5 |
|  |  | U6457 | 5 |

2. Sometimes, the ItemDescr field has data that is about 40 to 60 characters long. That results in the cell not showing the whole description. Is it possible to have that cell take the whole width of the maximum length of that item description? That way, I won't need to manually drag the cell width to show the entire description.

**My current VBA code looks like this:**

```
Sub CreateTabsFromData()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' This is the name of my main sheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    ' Sort source data
    With wsSource
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("A2:A" & lastRow), Header:=xlYes
    End With
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim currentCode As String
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim lastCode As String
    Dim startRow as Long
    lastCode = Left(wsSource.Cells(2, 1).Value, 4)
    startRow = 2
    For i = 2 To lastRow + 1 ' My sheet has a header, so starting from row 2.
        currentCode = Left(wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value, 4) ' Extracting the first 4 characters of the Itemcode
        If currentCode <> lastCode Then
            Set wsDestination = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(lastCode)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If wsDestination Is Nothing Then
                ' Creating a new worksheet for the code
                Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, wsSource)
                wsDestination.Name = lastCode
                wsDestination.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("ItemCode", "ItemDescr", "UnitNo", "Qty") ' Header row
            End If
            newRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wsSource.Rows(startRow & ":" & i - 1).Copy wsDestination.Cells(newRow, 1)
            lastCode = currentCode
            startRow = i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Set wsDestination = Nothing` just before `OERN`.

Comment: You'll  need to track newRow for each destination sheet.  Better to use `.End(xlup)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object `wsDestination` is assigned to an existing sheet (the sheet used in the previous code) whenever there is a change in currentCode.

Changes:

- `lastCode` to keep track of the previous code.
- Check and create a new worksheet only when `lastCode` is not equal to `currentCode`.

```vb
Sub CreateTabsFromData()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' This is the name of my main sheet
    Dim i As Long ' **
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim currentCode As String
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim lastCode As String ' **
    newRow = 2 ' Starting on the second row of the destination sheets because of header
    lastCode = Left(wsSource.Cells(2, 1).Value, 4)
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' My sheet has a header, so starting from row 2.
        currentCode = Left(wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value, 4) ' Extracting the first 4 characters of the Itemcode
        If currentCode <> lastCode Then  ' **
            Set wsDestination = Nothing ' **
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(currentCode)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If wsDestination Is Nothing Then
                ' Creating a new worksheet for the code
                Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, wsSource)
                wsDestination.Name = currentCode
                wsDestination.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("ItemCode", "ItemDescr", "UnitNo", "Qty") ' Header row
                newRow = 2
            End If
            lastCode = currentCode 
        End If  ' **
        ' Copy data to the destination sheet
        wsSource.Rows(i).Copy wsDestination.Cells(newRow, 1)
        newRow = newRow + 1
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**Update**

The revised code sorts the source table based on the first column and then efficiently copies all rows with the same code simultaneously.

```
Sub CreateTabsFromData()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' This is the name of my main sheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    ' Sort source data
    With wsSource
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("A2:A" & lastRow), Header:=xlYes
    End With
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim currentCode As String
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim lastCode As String
    Dim startRow as Long
    lastCode = Left(wsSource.Cells(2, 1).Value, 4)
    startRow = 2
    For i = 2 To lastRow + 1 ' My sheet has a header, so starting from row 2.
        currentCode = Left(wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value, 4) ' Extracting the first 4 characters of the Itemcode
        If currentCode <> lastCode Then
            Set wsDestination = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(lastCode)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If wsDestination Is Nothing Then
                ' Creating a new worksheet for the code
                Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, wsSource)
                wsDestination.Name = lastCode
                wsDestination.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("ItemCode", "ItemDescr", "UnitNo", "Qty") ' Header row
            End If
            newRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wsSource.Rows(startRow & ":" & i - 1).Copy wsDestination.Cells(newRow, 1)
            lastCode = currentCode
            startRow = i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**Update 2**

> Question: I would like to modify my VBA script to take all the data from ‘Sheet1’ and create tabs for each ItemCode and their subsequent data (like below). So, one unique item per tab.

```
Sub CreateTabsFromData()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' This is the name of my main sheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    ' Sort source data
    With wsSource
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("A2:A" & lastRow), Header:=xlYes
    End With
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim currentCode As String
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim lastCode As String
    Dim startRow as Long
    lastCode = wsSource.Cells(2, 1).Value ' *change*
    startRow = 2
    For i = 2 To lastRow + 1 ' My sheet has a header, so starting from row 2.
        currentCode = wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value ' *change*
        If currentCode <> lastCode Then
            Set wsDestination = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(lastCode)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If wsDestination Is Nothing Then
                ' Creating a new worksheet for the code
                Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, wsSource)
                wsDestination.Name = lastCode
                wsDestination.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("ItemCode", "ItemDescr", "UnitNo", "Qty") ' Header row
            End If
            newRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wsSource.Rows(startRow & ":" & i - 1).Copy wsDestination.Cells(newRow, 1)
            wsDestination.Columns("A:D").AutoFit ' *change*
            lastRow = wsDestination.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
            If lastRow > 2 Then
                wsDestination.Range("A2:B" & lastRow).ClearContents
            End If
            lastCode = currentCode
            startRow = i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I needed some tweaking with what I'm trying to achieve. I've updated my question to show exactly what I'm trying to achieve. Can you please help with what I need to change in my code to achieve that?

Comment: You just need to modify the way to populate `currentCode` and `lastCode'. Please see the revised code `Update2`. The change is marked w/ `*change*`.

Comment: Thank you so much. But is there a way to have the ItemCode data and ItemDescr data show only on the 1st row. All other rows to have different UnitNo and Qty. It would make it so much easier to read.

Comment: Four lines are added to get your expected result.

Comment: This worked but only the tabs are named the ItemCode. The actual row under the headers do not have any ItemCode data nor ItemDescr data in them.

Comment: It's a typo. I don't have time to test it before post. `If lastRow > 2 Then                 wsDestination.Range("A3:B" & lastRow).ClearContents`