# How to modify VBA script to create tabs based on item codes and subsequent information for them?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet ‘Sheet1’ that looks like this:

| ItemCode | ItemDescr | UnitNo | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD010204 | ABCD010204 description | U1234 | 10 |
| ABCD010204 | ABCD010204 description | U3421 | 10 |
| ABCD020206 | ABCD020206 description | U2345 | 30 |
| ABCD020206 | ABCD020206 description | U3542 | 30 |
| ABCD020206 | ABCD020206 description | U2456 | 30 |
| ABCD020408 | ABCD020408 description | U3456 | 20 |
| BCDE010203 | BCDE010203 description | U4567 | 5 |
| BCDE010203 | BCDE010203 description | U6457 | 5 |
| BCDE020206 | BCDE020206 description | U5678 | 15 |
| BCDE020206 | BCDE020206 description | U8567 | 15 |
| BCDE020410 | BCDE020410 description | U6789 | 20 |

The ItemCodes (about 40 of them) continue and are not standard logic and not always the same. But they are always 4 letters followed by usually 6 numbers, sometimes 4.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

1. Currently, I am able to create separate tabs for each item type (So, ABCD010204, ABCD020206, etc in the same tab. BCDE0100203, BCDE020206, BCDE020410, etc in another tab.)
   I would like to modify my VBA script to take all the data from ‘Sheet1’ and create tabs for each ItemCode and their subsequent data (like below). So, one unique item per tab.

| ItemCode | ItemDescr | UnitNo | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD010204 | ABCD010204 description | U1234 | 10 |
|  |  | U3421 | 10 |

| ItemCode | ItemDescr | UnitNo | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD020206 | ABCD020206 description | U2345 | 30 |
|  |  | U3542 | 30 |
|  |  | U2456 | 30 |

| ItemCode | ItemDescr | UnitNo | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BCDE010203 | BCDE010203 description | U4567 | 5 |
|  |  | U6457 | 5 |

2. Sometimes, the ItemDescr field has data that is about 40 to 60 characters long. That results in the cell not showing the whole description. Is it possible to have that cell take the whole width of the maximum length of that item description? That way, I won't need to manually drag the cell width to show the entire description.

**My current VBA code looks like this:**

```
Sub CreateTabsFromData()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' This is the name of my main sheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    ' Sort source data
    With wsSource
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("A2:A" & lastRow), Header:=xlYes
    End With
    Dim wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim currentCode As String
    Dim newRow As Long
    Dim lastCode As String
    Dim startRow as Long
    lastCode = Left(wsSource.Cells(2, 1).Value, 4)
    startRow = 2
    For i = 2 To lastRow + 1 ' My sheet has a header, so starting from row 2.
        currentCode = Left(wsSource.Cells(i, 1).Value, 4) ' Extracting the first 4 characters of the Itemcode
        If currentCode <> lastCode Then
            Set wsDestination = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(lastCode)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If wsDestination Is Nothing Then
                ' Creating a new worksheet for the code
                Set wsDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, wsSource)
                wsDestination.Name = lastCode
                wsDestination.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("ItemCode", "ItemDescr", "UnitNo", "Qty") ' Header row
            End If
            newRow = wsDestination.Cells(wsDestination.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wsSource.Rows(startRow & ":" & i - 1).Copy wsDestination.Cells(newRow, 1)
            lastCode = currentCode
            startRow = i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: There was a duplicate question raised by you, and a solution was given by @taller, but you have not replied to **taller** **[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77204354/8162520)** Should have replied they could have helped you, even the solution i see has been updated.

Comment: @NicolSmith I have updated the code on your previouse post.

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you a solution, which is made about in a click. Maybe you'll change your approach to the solution.

A pivot table can be such solution (it looks exactly as you stated, can be refreshed in one click):

[image]

It's the code to build this pivot table.

```
Sub Macro2()
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        [A1].CurrentRegion, Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet1!R3C6", TableName:="MyPT", DefaultVersion:=8
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MyPT")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = False
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
        With .PivotCache
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
        End With
        .RepeatAllLabels xlDoNotRepeatLabels
        With .PivotFields("ItemCode")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
            .Subtotals = _
                Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
        End With
        With .PivotFields("ItemDescr")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 2
            .Subtotals = _
                Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
        End With
        With .PivotFields("UnitNo")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 3
        End With
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Qty"), "Sum of Qty", xlSum
        .InGridDropZones = True
        .RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
        .ColumnGrand = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that using a macro. So, I'll take any solution right now. I'm open to trying out your solution. How do I go about it?